# Plugin bridge error with docker compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10

I have Docker Desktop installed for Windows 10.

When I do:

> docker-compose up

I get an error:

> Creating network "docker_sandbox" with driver "bridge" ERROR: could
>   not find plugin bridge in v1 plugin registry: plugin not found

On the Docker site, they say Docker Compose comes installed with the desktop installation and should work out of box.

Do I need some configuration changes to get it working?

This is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.3.2
    volumes: ["./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"]
    ports: ["9090:9090"]
    networks: ["sandbox"]

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:5.2.1
    volumes: ["./grafana/plugins/cinnamon-prometheus-app:/var/lib/grafana/plugins/cinnamon-prometheus-app"]
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
    networks: ["sandbox"]
    depends_on: ["prometheus"]

networks:
  sandbox:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Can you include your `docker-compose.yml` file in the question?  Does the same file work in other environments (a native Linux VM, Docker Desktop, ...)?

Comment: ...have you reconfigured your Docker for Swarm mode?  Does just deleting all of the `networks:` and relying on the `default` network that Compose creates on its own work?

Comment: I haven't done anything extra for docker. I just installed it and started it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running in a **Windows container mode**, then here's what worked for me:

Update the network definition in the `docker-compose` to nat.

```
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: nat
```

Comment: Super!! @Bartosz